# Can I get vim to correctly indent this Ruby code (Nokogiri)?

Tags: vim, ruby, indentation

The first [XML Builder Example](http://nokogiri.rubyforge.org/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/Builder.html) for Nokogiri looks like this:

```
builder = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new do |xml|
    xml.root {
      xml.products {
        xml.widget {
          xml.id_ "10"
          xml.name "Awesome widget"
        }
      }
    }
 end
 puts builder.to_xml
```

Even though I have the [Ruby Vim files](http://vim-ruby.rubyforge.org/) installed, Vim's autoindent flattens the above example like this:

```
builder = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new do |xml|
  xml.root {
    xml.products {
    xml.widget {
    xml.id_ "10"
    xml.name "Awesome widget"
  }
  }
  }
end
puts builder.to_xml
```

Does anybody know how to get Vim to autoindent this correctly?

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce this.

The indentation rules are defined in the function `GetRubyIndent`, which is in `/usr/share/vim/vimcurrent/indent/ruby.vim` on Linux and Unix systems.

The problem seems to be that `GetMSL` returns 8 for line 3, but also returns 8 rather than 12 for line 4.

If you have a bit of time, have a look at the source code and try to find and fix the problem.

If not, you might like to report it as a bug at the [RubyForge Vim/Ruby project site](http://rubyforge.org/projects/vim-ruby).